# htaccess redirect remove category slug from url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using .htaccess file in apache server, how can I get

```
http://mysite/[category]/[post-title]
```

redirect to

```
http://mysite/[post-title]
```

where [category] and [post-title] could be any category name and post-titles respectively.

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress i recommend that plugin

[WP No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)

it works like a charm with my blog